# How was the minimal complete definition Ord chosen?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

[`Data.Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html) includes these methods:

```
compare :: a -> a -> Ordering

(<) :: a -> a -> Bool

(<=) :: a -> a -> Bool

(>) :: a -> a -> Bool

(>=) :: a -> a -> Bool

max :: a -> a -> a

min :: a -> a -> a
```

The minimal complete definition is `compare | (<=)`.

I understand how the other methods can be determined from either of these two methods.

I don't understand why `(>)` (for example) can't also be used as a minimal complete definition. `not (a > b)` is equivalent to `a <= b`.

Was the decision for `(>)` to be excluded as a minimal complete definition arbitrary, or am I missing something?

Comment: My first guess would be that most mathematical papers define a ≤ operator for an order relation.

Comment: The "minimal complete definition" concept is intended to allow the class author to declare the minimum set of definitions *their implementation of the class* requires to function. The minimum set depends on the implementation details of default methods, not just on the logical relationships among the abstract methods. The minimal definition mechanism was never intended to allow the class user to pick *any* minimal set of definitions that logically could suffice to implement the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#Ord) sheds a little bit of light on this:

```hs
class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where
    compare              :: a -> a -> Ordering
    (<), (<=), (>), (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    max, min             :: a -> a -> a

    compare x y = if x == y then EQ
                  else if x <= y then LT
                  else GT

    x <  y = case compare x y of { LT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x <= y = case compare x y of { GT -> False; _ -> True }
    x >  y = case compare x y of { GT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x >= y = case compare x y of { LT -> False; _ -> True }
```

As you can see all comparisons are implemented in terms of `compare` and compare itself is implemented in terms of `<=`. The choice is kind of arbitrary (although as Willem van Onsem writes it probably originates from mathematical tradition), but this does rule out allowing an additional operator to be used as minimal definition. There can only be one default definition of `compare`.